# Regex exact pattern matching with a variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to detect the exact patterns in text from the lst list but not when it is a part of other words. I know that I can use anchors to match exactly the pattern but it doesn't work with variables. Will appreciate your help!

```
lst = ['Test', 'Pink', 'Blue', 'Green']
text = 'Testing and Pink. Blue is my fav color. Greenwood is my name.'
def get_words_from_lst(text, lst):
    words = []        
    for word in lst:
        if r'{}'.format(word) in text:
            words.append(word)
    print(words)
get_words_from_lst(text, lst)
```

desired output: `['Pink', 'Blue']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Regex** with `boundaries (\b)`

**Demo:**

```
import re
lst = ['Test', 'Pink', 'Blue', 'Green']
text = 'Testing and Pink. Blue is my fav color. Greenwood is my name.'
def get_words_from_lst(text, lst):
    #print([word for word in lst if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b", text)])   #Single line list comprehension 
    words = []
    for word in lst:
        if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b", text):
            words.append(word)
    print(words)
get_words_from_lst(text, lst)
```

**Output:**

```
['Pink', 'Blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to split the letter groups (words) from punctuation then use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [word for word in re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]',text) if word in lst]
['Pink', 'Blue']
```

Or, alternatively:

```
>>> [word for word in re.split(r'\W',text) if word in lst]
['Pink', 'Blue']
```

In either case, the support for unicode is limited if you use `re.split`.  Python `re` module does not support `[^\p{L}]` that would allow a split on any non-letter unicode character.

You can also approach it as a filter and do:

```
>>> [word for word in lst if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), text)]
['Pink', 'Blue']
```

or

```
>>> filter(lambda w: re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), text), lst)
['Pink', 'Blue']
```

But the first method would be faster if you have ascii only text. The second method does support unicode with proper flags.

Answer (score 0):

Split the text by non word characters `\W`. Then find the intersection of the two lists.

```
set(lst).intersection(re.split('\W', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join`:

```
import re
lst = ['Test', 'Pink', 'Blue', 'Green']
text = 'Testing and Pink. Blue is my fav color. Greenwood is my name.' 
new_text = re.findall('|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(i) for i in lst), text)
```

Output:

```
['Pink', 'Blue']
```